# How to change the slider image dynamically

Tags: vue.js

Thanks for browsing!

I am creating a slider with vue-image-lightbox.

[image]

However, now that I have a static src listed in the sample and the image is a slider, I would like to change this src to a dynamic one and display the image accordingly.

So I wrote the code as shown below, but the img src is set to undefind and the image is not displayed.

[image]

I thought I stored /uploads/1 here, but it is undefind.

**So I'm hoping you can tell me how to store /uploads/1 in src and thumb.**

I would like to ask for your wisdom.

```
<template>
  <div>
      <figure class="mr-3">
        <a class="img-box" @click.prevent.stop="show(0)">
          <img
              :src="post.main_image_url"
              :alt="post.main_image_url"
          >
        </a>
      </figure>
    <ImageLightBox :media="media" ref="lightbox" :show-light-box="false" :show-caption="true"></ImageLightBox>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ImageLightBox from 'vue-image-lightbox';

require("vue-image-lightbox/dist/vue-image-lightbox.min.css");

export default {
  name: 'lightbox',
  components: {
    ImageLightBox,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      post: {},
      post_main_image_url: '',
      media: [
        {
          // src: "/uploads/1" will work.
          thumb: this.post_main_image_url,
          src: this.post_main_image_url,
          title: '朝日が昇る摩周湖（北海道川上郡弟子屈町）',
        },
      ],
    }
  },

  methods: {
    show: function(index){
      this.$refs.lightbox.showImage(index)
    },
    // data acquisition process
    getData() {
      this.$loading.load(
          this.$auth.api.get(
              'posts/' + this.post_id, {
                params: {}
              }
          ).then(res => {
            this.post = res.data.post;

            let mainImageUrl = res.data.post.main_image_url;
            console.log(mainImageUrl)
              // =>/uploads/1
            let stringMainImageUrl = String(mainImageUrl)
            console.log(stringMainImageUrl)
              // =>/uploads/1
            this.post_main_image_url = stringMainImageUrl
            console.log(String(this.post_main_image_url))
              // =>/uploads/1
          }).catch(err => {
            this.$errorHandlers.initial(err);
          })
      )
    }

  }
  created() {
    this.getData();
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey just looked at your code, here are a couple of things:

```html
 // I couldn't find `show` method, is it declared?
 <a class="img-box" @click.prevent.stop="show(0)">
```

```html
<!-- You are initializing 'post' as empty string and I don't see a mounted hook
 for initializing this property 'main_image_url'  --> 
<img :src="post.main_image_url" :alt="post.main_image_url" />
```

```js
  data() {
    return {
      post: {},
      post_main_image_url: '', 
      media: [
        {
/* When the component is mounted both properties will get initialized with an empty string.
You might need to initialize properties within the "mounted" hook. */
          thumb: this.post_main_image_url, 
          src: this.post_main_image_url,
```

```js
// I don't see this method being called anywhere in the code
getData() {
      this.$loading.load(
        this.$auth.api
          .get('posts/' + this.post_id, {
            params: {}
          })
```

Comment: thankyou.Added show method.getData() is used for 'created'.

Comment: Do you mean to use the "mounted" hook to include the contents?

Comment: Yes in a nutshell you want to make sure that the data is loaded properly before you render it in the template. I'm not really familiar with the library nor the code, if you still have issues upload a small demo to codesandbox or anything similar and I'll take a look. Otherwise my discord is PawFV#8830.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but what exactly is the solution to undefind, for example?
I have tried many things, but they did not work, so please let me know.

Comment: It might be, I lack a bit of context here if you wanna setup a call then we can take a look and I could probably point you out a little bit better.